# Only write back changes when restoring a disk image with dd

Tags: partition, dd, ssd, disk-image

Given a physical disk and an image created from it, I want to write the image back onto the physical disk, but *only* write the **changed** bytes or sectors. The use case is restoring images on an SSD - unlike HDDs these have a limited number of writes. The added reads do not cause wear on the SSD and might even speed up the restore process when barely anything changed.

```
  writing this img   [___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___]
back onto this disk: [___|___|_ab|c__|___|___|___|xyz|___] 
      actual writes:  nnn nnn YYY YYY nnn nnn nnn YYY nnn
```

If the writes are not per-sector (here: 3-byte sectors) but bytewise that would work as well. A final statistic regarding the number of total writes would be nice, too. `dd` can't do that, is there an existing tool for that?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343762/update-block-device-with-image-while-writing-only-the-delta-is-it-possible

Comment: You may also look at bsdiff / bsdpatch utilities in FreeBSD or google their sources for other OSes.